# Cant load 2 jquery scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript, that loads new posts on website from database before :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function LoadContent() {
        patch = window.location.toString();
       if (patch!== undefined && patch=="http://i-sc.ru/" || patch=="http://i-sc.ru/index.php") {
        $.ajax({
        url: patch,
        success: function(content) {
    $('#dle-content').html($('#dle-content', content).html());
    }})}

    setTimeout("LoadContent()", 50);
    }

    </script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
LoadContent()

});
      </script>
```

And after  i have set up script for

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancyzoom.js"></script>
```

that i put in `<head>`

set up:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  //Set the default directory to find the images needed
  //by the plugin (closebtn.png, blank.gif, loading images ....)
  $.fn.fancyzoom.defaultsOptions.imgDir='../images/'; //very important must finish with a /

  $('a.tozoom').fancyzoom({Speed:0});

  $('a').fancyzoom({overlay:0.6});

  //new rev > 1.2
  //apply fancyzoom effect on all image whose class is fancyzoom !!

  $('img.fancyzoom').fancyzoom();
});
</script>
```

Well, now about the problem:

When the website is loaded, i cant zoom images because of conflict, i think

How to solve it?

Comment: You should remove the `<script>` tags from `js/jquery.fancyzoom.js` and see if that works.

Comment: Most of the times such a thing happens because the same js gets loaded  multiple times. Be sure that it is not so .

Answer (score 0):

Don't reference `jquery.js` file multiple times, from the second script, remove the reference to the file.

And ensure you are not referencing `different versions` of `.js` files any where in your script.